# Possible to have Rule Tiles work with Rule Tiles in other Tilemaps in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap, tiles

I am using Rule Tiles to draw walls for my top down 2D Unity game. I have already been able to implement custom Rule Tiles that will work with each other (ie two different Rule Tile setups that still auto-tile together) but now I want to do the same but with Tiles that are in different Tilemaps.

The reason I have different tile maps is so that I can specify different behavior for certain sections of my walls when the player hits it. My idea is that I can paint my walls using either the "default" tilemap that just has basic colliders, OR I can paint parts of the wall with a different tilemap so that section of the wall has a certain behavior. All while all of the tiles still auto-tile and auto-update to look correct.

Is this possible? It seems that Rule Tiles simply are not aware of Tiles in other Tilemaps at all. If this isn't possible, is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You may need [CustomRulesForRuleTile](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.tilemap.extras@1.6/manual/CustomRulesForRuleTile.html). And access other tilemap data in your custom rules.